# Unhandled promise rejection in Docker with 'opn' npm module

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, npm, promise

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Exited with code 3
```

I apparently get this error when I open links using the module in Docker container. I tested the code in my local before I put the code on my server which uses Docker. And It literally works well in my local that doesn't use Docker. So I assume that something is wrong with docker but there's actually no way to figure out what the problem is. Is there anyone who has ever used 'opn' module with Docker?

```
app.use('/:encoded_id', function(req, res) {
let base58Id = req.params.encoded_id;
let id = base58.decode(base58Id)
Url.findOne({ _id:id }, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    if (doc) {
      opn(doc.long_url[i]);
     }
    else res.redirect(config.webhost);
 })
});
```

Comment: You're going to have to be a _lot_ more specific with this question; where's your code that calls `opn`? Add a `process.on('unhandledRejection', err => { console.error(err.stack); throw err; });` so you can see the actual error.

Comment: @Jacob I just added the code. By the way, after I set node version of my server to the same as my local one, It doesn't says the promise error anymore but still doesn't open any links.

Comment: @Jacob I'm going to try to add your code but I'm not sure where should I put the code in.

Comment: It should just run during startup. My code is for logging the error, not fixing anything (since I have no idea what's broken); what error do you see?

Comment: @Jacob http://pastebin.com/uAEW8JCT this is what I got

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Exit code 3](https://github.com/sindresorhus/opn/blob/master/xdg-open#L84) means that:

> A required tool could not be found.

You say that the goal is to "open links", so the Docker container probably does not have a browser (or at least a default browser, anyway).

If you are sure that the required software is installed, it is probably a configuration issue. In this case, you can work around it by specifying the [app option](https://github.com/sindresorhus/opn#app). But try to avoid using it if you can, as it is platform dependent and so will make your code less portable.

Comment: Why does the Docker suppose to have a browser? I just want people to open links when they enter my website not the docker.

Comment: `opn` is for opening files/URLs/etc _in a desktop environment_; what are you trying to do? I'm confused what you mean by "open links." You mean hyperlink `<a/>` tags?!

Comment: @Jacob I'm making a website that compress multiple links to one link. and If I try to open multiple links in client-side(using javascript), popup blocker prevents to open multiple links. but If I use `opn` module in server-side, It helps me to avoid the popup blockers. so basically this is why I use `opn`

Comment: Oh man... `opn` works on your _local_ machine because it's opening links on your own computer; it won't let a remote server open links on a client's desktop!

Comment: @Jacob Is there any way to do what I want to do?

Comment: The `opn` module on npm is basically a JavaScript API equivalent of the `open` command in your terminal. E.g. if I go to my terminal and run `open package.json` it opens [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) because that is my default text editor. And if I run `open http://example.com` it opens Google Chrome, because that is my default browser. This is what `open` does and also what [opn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opn) does. It just opens stuff for you, on your own machine.

Comment: @PhillipYS first you should visit [npmjs.com](https://npmjs.com) or [npms.io](https://npms.io) and try to find other projects that do what you want. If you really can't find anything, come back here and post a new question.